# C++, Changing value in one array changes another array

Tags: c++, arrays

I have a 2D array which originally looks like the following
qrow are defined earlier in my code. I have an input query.txt file, which essentially count the rows of that text file with a loop, and define

```
int qrow = result of the loop count
```

This value is not changed later on in the code.
Similarly for attrow. In this specific test case,

```
qrow = 10
attrow = 19
```

Usage Matrix:

```
int usage [qrow][attrow];
// Assigned values using a while loop

Usage matrix
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 1 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0

0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

0 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1

0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0

0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Then I created another array as following:

```
int aq [qrow][attrow];
```

I assigned value to aq matrix with another while loop, however I notice if I print out my usage matrix again, values were changed. In specific I found the following example

```
cout<<"Before, usage[0][7] = "<<usage[0][7]<<endl;
aq[10][9] = 20;
cout<<"After, usage[0][7] = "<<usage[0][7]<<endl;
```

Output:

```
Before, usage[0][7] = 1
After, usage[0][7] = 20
```

Can anyone explain why is this behaving this way? Also appreciate potential resolution to this problem. Thanks!

FYI, below is the actual while loop which is causing this issue,

```
while(a<qrow){
    while(b<attrow){
    // Compute A(att=a, q = b)
    // initialise aq entry to zero
    aq[b][a] = 0;

    int use = usage[b][a];
    if (use == 0){
        aq[a][b] = 0;
        b=b+1;
        continue;
    }
    int sum = 0;
    int k = 0;
    while ( k< freqcol){
            double temp = freqMat[b][k];
            sum = sum + temp;
            k=k+1;
        }
        aq[b][a] = sum;
        b=b+1;
    }
a=a+1;
b=0;
```

}

Usage matrix after loop,

```
Usage matrix
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 1 -2147483648 -2147483648

-2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 -2147483648 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0

0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a proper [mre]. What is `qrow`? What is `attrow`? How are they defined? How are they initialized?

Comment: My crystal ball says you're accessing outside the bounds of one of the arrays and happen to stomp on the other.

Comment: `int aq [qrow][attrow];` -- If `qrow` and `attrow` are not `const`, then this is not valid C++.  Arrays in C++ must have their size denoted by a constant expression, not a runtime computed value.

Comment: Also, you define `int aq [qrow][attrow];` and use the loops `while(a<qrow)` and `while(b<attrow)`. ***But*** then you also use `aq[b][a] = 0` which will work if and only if `qrow == attrow`. Otherwise you *will* go out of bounds and have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Your code is only correct if qrow == attrow. You swap row and column acces. usage[b][a] AND you use usage[a][b]. In other cases you run out of one of the arrays and possibly start overwriting the others

Comment: Thanks for your kind replies. I apologize I am relatively new to coding. Please let me know if there is any additional information that should be provided. Also thanks to P Kramer I will check again with my while loop you point out1

Comment: I also recommend you to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. Then it's easy to see if one index becomes out of bounds.

Comment: Update, after changing my while loop to aq[a][b], the usage matrix remain the same throughout the test. Much appreciated. However I don't under if the loop is running after I did "aq[10][9] = 20;" in the question, how would this affect the result above to be correct?

Comment: `int qrow = <result of some calculation>` – it does not matter if you change `qrow` afterwards or not, it remains invalid C++. `qrow` must be constant at compile time, otherwise it is not legal C++. If using GCC, try switching off compiler extensions by setting `-std=C++XX` with XX defining the standard you use, e. g. 20 (or 17, 14, 11, ...).

Comment: If the values of the dimensions can change at run-time then use `std::vector` instead.

Comment: And to come back to the already mentioned indices out of bounds: With `qrow == 10 && attrow == 19` and if you have `b == 18` what do you think you where you will be accessing `aq[b]`???

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude just hinted me to a good comparison: *Standard* C++ arrays (not VLA you are using which is a *compiler extension*) behave like `std::array`. Try to create such an array with your values `qrow` and `attrow` computed at runtime...

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Regarding to my update earlier, I made a incorrect statement. changing aq[a][b] in my loop DID NOT resolve the issue. However, I will double check with my bonds as well as try with std::array, and update the question later on.

Answer (score 1):

Without being to able to tell exactly what's going on, you're most likely going out of bounds with your array indices.

If both arrays are on the stack, their memory regions will be adjacent:

```
Array 1:                              Array 2:
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
```

Now if you go out of bounds with your array indices, you're likely to write to the memory of the other array. For example, if you do `array2[-1] = 20`, you will write to the last element of the first array:

```
Array 1:                              Array 2:
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
                          array2[-1]^ ^array2[0]
```

Likewise, you will write to array 2 if you're using too large indices to access array 1:

```
Array 1:                              Array 2:
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX|XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
          array1[length_of_array1-1]^ ^array1[length_of_array1]
```

Needless to say: *DON'T* do this on purpose. This just serves to explain what you're observing and doing this is *undefined behavior*, i.e. you cannot rely on this to happen.

Possible solution: Use STL containers like `std::array` or `std::vector` and use iterators or a range-based for loop to safely iterate over the elements, like so:

```
#include <array>

std::array<int, 10> array1;
// Fill array somehow
...

for (auto& i : array1) {   // reference here, because we want to write to the element
   // do something
}
```

With nested `std::vector`s, in case you need runtime values for the size:

```
#include <vector>

size_t rows, columns;
...

std::vector<std::vector<int>> array1{};

// here we resize the vectors to have the desired number of elements
array1.resize(rows);
for (auto& row : array1) {
   row.resize(columns);
}

for (auto& row : array1) {
   for (auto& element : row) {
      // do something
   }
}
```

If you absolutely have to use indices, make sure you're not going out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I will test out with your suggested method.

Comment: Using std::array<int, 10> array1; What is the correct syntax if I want to define a 2D array?

Comment: That would be `std::array<std::array<int, M>, N>>`, `M` and `N` being the respective array dimensions.

Comment: @WayneTan Be aware, though, that with this approach you are exploring the field of *undefined behaviour* and such a programme is not valid according to the standard. It's pretty likely that you can observe described behaviour, but there's no *guarantee* for...

Comment: @WayneTan Note that with 2D `std::array` you need to invert the dimensions you actually want to use, i.e. to get the equivalent to `int[row][column]` you need to write `std::array<int, column>, row>`. That's due to how templates work and that's actually where I regret standard committee having defined `template <typename T, size_t S>class array {...}` instead of `template <size_t S, typename T>class array {...}`.

Comment: Does M, N has to be actual numbers? I try to define the dimension with qrow, attrow similarly, and it is giving me an error. My issue is that, depending on the test inputs, the dimension can vary.

Comment: @WayneTan Look at the comments to question – they refer to exactly that already... In short: You need to use *compile time constants*, actually for both `std::array` *and* classic array (at least to be standard conformant; otherwise in the classic case you define a VLA which is a compiler extension, but non-standard).

Comment: @WayneTan as already pointed out, these must be compile-time constants. If you need variable size containers, use `std::vector` for example: `std::vector<std::vector<int>>`